# How to import/restore .vmg SMS backup to Android?

Tags: sms, restore

I have got an old Samsung mobile that exports all the SMS messages in `.vmg` format. How can I restore those messages on my Android?

Is there any tool to convert `.vmg` messages to `.xml` so I could restore using SMS Backup & Restore?

Or is there any app to restore from `.vmg` files directly like the one, SDBackup, unfortunately, which didn't work for me?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to try [Import SMS from Windows Phone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smsbackup.leonardocezary.smsimporter) app. It imports unlimited SMS messages from both .vmsg and .msg. It is free and you can find it on Google Play Store.

If you have MMS messages or group conversations to import, try the PRO version, called [Import SMS from Windows Phone PRO](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smsbackup.leonardocezary.smsimporter.pro). It also imports unlimited MMS or SMS messages, but is a paid version. You can also find it on Play Store.

Comment: Hi, looks like you're affiliated with the app. While it's okay to refer to a product written by yourself, take note that *explicit disclosure is required on the post itself*. Please read [How to not be a spammer](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).

Answer (score -1):

I've made an app called [VMG Converter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aoe.vmgconverter), you can get it from Google Play

Depending on your old phone, it might be able to import your messages from VMG files into Android. The app is free.

Comment: Also, this *free* app just welcomed me with a "Purchase Unlocker" dialog.